# Include period in string if condition exists (inline)

Tags: powershell

I have variable $a in a foreach loop.

I want to set a string for a filename.

```
$server = "mysqlservername"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum') | out-null
$My='Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo'
$srv = new-object ("$My.Server") $Server
$scripter = new-object ("$My.Scripter") $srv 
$scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = $true   

$a = new-object System.Data.Datatable

$a=$srv.databases[$Database].EnumObjects([long]0x1FFFFFFF -band $all) 

$a | FOREACH-OBJECT 
{
$scripter.Options.Filename = "$($_.schema).$($_.name)"
#then script out an object using that filename)
$UrnCollection = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.urnCollection')
$URNCollection.add($_.urn)
$scripter.script($URNCollection)
}
```

I want the filename to be "schema.name", but only if $_.schema exists (not all objects have a schema).  If it doesn't, I want it to be just "name"

I'm not sure if, when it's empty, $a.schema is blank or null or empty.  Not sure if that matters.

The way it's set currently, if schema is empty(?), the filename is ".myobjectnamehere".

Is there a way to do it in one line?  I could do it with a ton of IF conditions, but I'd rather do it inline if I can. Thanks.

Here's the contents of $a | gm

```
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name                MemberType            Definition                                                                   
----                ----------            ----------                                                                   
AcceptChanges       Method                void AcceptChanges()                                                         
BeginEdit           Method                void BeginEdit()                                                             
CancelEdit          Method                void CancelEdit()                                                            
ClearErrors         Method                void ClearErrors()                                                           
Delete              Method                void Delete()                                                                
EndEdit             Method                void EndEdit()                                                               
Equals              Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                               
GetChildRows        Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataR...
GetColumnError      Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError(string colum...
GetColumnsInError   Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()                                 
GetHashCode         Method                int GetHashCode()                                                            
GetParentRow        Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow...
GetParentRows       Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), System.Data.Data...
GetType             Method                type GetType()                                                               
HasVersion          Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)                          
IsNull              Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), bool IsNull(...
RejectChanges       Method                void RejectChanges()                                                         
SetAdded            Method                void SetAdded()                                                              
SetColumnError      Method                void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), void SetColumnError(st...
SetModified         Method                void SetModified()                                                           
SetParentRow        Method                void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), void SetParentRow(System...
ToString            Method                string ToString()                                                            
Item                ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(string ...
DatabaseObjectTypes Property              string DatabaseObjectTypes {get;set;}                                        
Name                Property              string Name {get;set;}                                                       
Schema              Property              string Schema {get;set;}                                                     
Urn                 Property              string Urn {get;set;}
```

Comment: Can you add results of $a | gm What does $a look like?

Comment: What do you mean by if `$_.first exists`? Exists where? If you want us to optimize your code, be sure to include your unoptimized version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pseudo code does not seem to match what you describing, without knowing what actual code $a properties looks like, I will just guess you want something like this:

```
$a | % {
 if ($_.first) { 
     $c.options.filename = "$($_.First).$($_.last)" 
 } else {
     $c.options.filename = $_.last
 }
}
```

Comment: Right, but is there a way to do that inline (aka without the if/else)?  Otherwise this'll work.  Thanks!

Comment: I've got to do slightly different versions of that in several places.  But 7 of the 10 can be replaced with the exact same thing, so I can change it to a variable.  I'll go that way, then.  Thanks!